# Entity Framework Group BY causing Unable to cast object of type 'System.DBNull' to type 'System.String'

Tags: c#, mysql, linq, group-by, entity-framework-6

I am trying to run following EF query and return the exception on some instances of Databases

```
//Contacts Stats  summary 
Dictionary<ContactStatusEnum, int> contactStats = (await context.Contacts.ToListAsync())
                                            .GroupBy(n => n.Status)
                                            .ToDictionary(x => x.Key, x => x.Count());
```

This is causing an exception
Exception:Unable to cast object of type 'System.DBNull' to type 'System.String'.

At same time i executed sql

```
SELECT status,COUNT(*) FROM contacts group BY STATUS
```

and is getting executed without any errors. Plus there are status value exists for all contact records

The same code is working agaist the stage or DEV db

Comment: Not sure if it helps or not, do you try query to check whether there is a record with Status is `null`? `SELECT COUNT(*) FROM contacts WHERE status IS NULL`

Comment: All contacts got a Status value

Comment: This will casue error Unable to translate the given 'GroupBy' pattern. Call 'AsEnumerable' before 'GroupBy' to evaluate it client-side.'  @Charlieface
Also the column will not allow NULL values in database,

Comment: You should be able to do it like this `await context.Contacts.Where(n => n.Status != null).GroupBy(n => n.Status).Select(x => new { x.Key, Count = x.Count() }).ToDictionaryAsync(x => x.Key, x => x.Count)`

Comment: Adding a intermediate  step before converting to Dictionary seems to resolve the issue
 .Select(x => new { x.Key, Count = x.Count() })  If you can add this comment as an answer I can mark this thread as answered

Answer (score 1):

you can modify as below

```
//Contacts Stats  summary 
Dictionary<ContactStatusEnum, int> contactStats = (await context.Contacts.Where(cn=>cn.status!=null).ToListAsync())
                                        .GroupBy(n => n.Status)
                                        .ToDictionary(x => x.Key, x => x.Count());
```

else follow this one

```
//Contacts Stats  summary 
Dictionary<ContactStatusEnum, int> contactStats = (await context.Contacts.ToListAsync())
                                    .GroupBy(n => n.Status ?? string.Empty)
                                    .ToDictionary(x => x.Key, x => x.Count());
```

Comment: Here column Status is not of type String This is of type enum as per Entity Framework definition 
Plus its a column which will not allow NULL values in table